# A particular case of L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined on an open interval $(a,b)$ which has continuous derivatives of order $1,2, \dots , n-1$, and there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c), f^{{1}}(c), \dots , f^{(n-1)}(c)$ are all $0$.  However $f^{n}(c)$ is not $0$ and we can assume that $f^{n}(x) > 0$ for $x \in (a,b)$, however **no assumptions about the continuity of** $f^{(n)}(x)$ **are made**. 
In this case is it true that $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{(x-c)^n} = \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}$?

Comment: That's L'Hôpital to you.

Comment: @Noldorin: that's my preferred spelling too.  From [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html): *Note that l'Hospital's name is commonly seen spelled both "l'Hospital" (e.g., Maurer 1981, p. 426; Arfken 1985, p. 310) and "l'Hôpital" (e.g., Maurer 1981, p. 426; Gray 1997, p. 529), the two being equivalent in French spelling.*

Comment: @Isaac: Yeah. The circumflex accent represents a missing 's', and is the more common (less archaic) spelling... It represents pronunciation better for sure.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital's rule does not depend on the continuity of the derivative.  Under your conditions, $\lim_{x\to c}f^{(k)}(x)=0$ for $k\le n-1$, so l'Hospital's rule can be applied to give:
$$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{(x-c)^n}
=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{n(x-c)^{n-1}}
=\cdots
=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)}{n!(x-c)}
=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}.
$$

However, to assert that $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}$ requires that $f^{(n)}$ be continuous at $c$. ($n!$ is independent of $x$, so $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f^{(n)}(x)=f^{(n)}(c)$ are equivalent and the latter is the definition of continuity for $f^{(n)}$ at $c$.)